# .Net Msi installer encounters error - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-installer

I have created msi installer which installs WCF windows service.

Whenever I try to install it then it encounters below error:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Logging, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Logging, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

However, Logging assembly is loading properly.

Detailed Error:

```js
Detailed error:

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\xxx\System\xxxxx.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Logging, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/xxx/System/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : xxxService, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\xxx\System\xxxxx.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/xxx/System/Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/xxx/System/Logging/Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/xxx/System/Logging.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/xxx/System/Logging/Logging.EXE.
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: "However, Logging assembly is loading properly" Are you sure? the error says that it could not load it.

Comment: Logging project is building with one warning:- Warning 1 Assembly generation -- The version '10.0.70958.0' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format Logging

Comment: The Logging.dll compiles, ok... But it does not mean that the installer project detects it as a reference and include it into the installer. Have you noticed the difference in the version numbers `Logging, Version=3.5.0.0` vs `The version '10.0.70958.0' specified for the 'file version' is not...`? Looks like a dll versioning problem.